# Positioning bottom border underneath the bullet of an ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, border

http://jsfiddle.net/G34yN/7/

Anybody know how to position bottom border underneath the bullet of an ordered list?

```
ol li {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add:

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/G34yN/8/

You'll probably want to modify the left padding a bit.

Comment: Anybody know how to display the <li> inline where list-style-position: inside and <a> display: block? http://jsfiddle.net/G34yN/18/